# (tag:tagname) links to Stack Overflow tags, not Meta Stack Overflow tags

Tags: support, tags, markdown, editor

Right now, I can use `[tag:tagname]` almost anywhere on Stack Overflow to link to a tag. On Meta Stack Overflow, I can use the same markup, but it still links to tags on Stack Overflow, and not Meta Stack Overflow.

Can we have something like `[tag:meta:tagname]` and `[tag:main:tagname]`, where plain `[tag:tagname]` goes to the site which the question/comment is being posted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's already syntax for Meta tags: `[meta-tag:tagname]` -> [tagname](/questions/tagged/tagname). As for `[tag:tagname]` being site-sensitive, that's an incompatible change to a lot of old posts and you'll need some good reasons to get it changed. (Also, using two colons to refer to an SO tag, as in `[tag:main:stackoverflow]`, just seems unwieldy.)

Comment: Got it. I changed the post to [meta-tag:support] instead of feature request. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `meta-tag` to link to tag pages on meta.

like `[meta-tag:editor]` to point to [editor](/questions/tagged/editor)